# Class 'Zend\Filter\AbstractFilter' not found in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Server with Zend Framework 2 and I created my first application without library and the application works (there is only a echo). When I put Zend folder of Zend Framework 2.2.5, Zend Server in Overview told me this error: Class 'Zend\Filter\AbstractFilter' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs**projectname**\library\Zend\Filter\Inflector.php

If I use Zend Framework 1 this error isn't anymore view but i would use ZF2, how can I fix it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Chances are you're missing an autoloader or your include path is not set correctly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP solved!

Comment: how you solved that issue i am also facing same problem